# fast way to evaluate the maximum value of a discrete bivariate function

Tags: r, optimization

Let's suppose I have a function f(x,y) and two vectors X and Y, and I want two find the combination of the values X and Y that gives the maximum value of f .

*The function is well defined and bounded. X and Y have approximately 1000 elements each.

*The function is continuous, but I only need the highest point from the vector X and Y even though the maximum might be somewhere in between.

One possible implementation is to use two nested for loops such as in this  example; where each x and y are 10-element vectors and z=f(x,y)=x+y

> ```
> max =-1 
> for (x in 1:10){
>    for (y in 2:20){
>        z = x+y
>        if (z>max){
>            z=max
>            x_sol = x
>            y_sol = y
>        }
>    }
> }
> x_sol #10
> y_sol #20
> ```

This code shows that the maximum value for all the possible combinations of x and y is when (x,y)=(10,20). This code is fine; the problem with is that when x and y hold more values, z is more complex, and this procedure has to run hundreds of times, it's slow.
I was wondering if there is a more elegant method that replaces the nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use this brute-force approach to optimization, vectorization is usually the fastest way to achieve what you are trying to do:

```
x <- 1:100
y <- 1:100

df <- expand.grid(x=x,y=y)

df$z <- df$x + df$y

max(df$z)
```

This solution of course depends on the kind of function you want to use.

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for. The only problem is that it doesn't return the values of x and y that maximizes the function

Comment: you can simply extract that row of the df with `df[which.max(df$z),]`.

Answer (score 0):

There are various optimization methods you can use instead of brute-force search if the function has certain properties. If the function is linear, you can use the techniques of linear programming, such as the simplex algorithm. If the function is linear and the independent variables must be integers, that’s integer linear programming, for which a number of algorithms exist.  If it’s not just continuous but differentiable, you can use the gradients to find local maxima.

Comment: This is part of a dynamic programming algorithm using the Bellman equation. So, it is not worth spending resources trying to find the exact value on every iteration, as an approximation will suffice for the iterations to converge to the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Maybe search for a local max by following gradients, if an approximation will do.  You risk getting trapped on a foothill. Or sample a subset of the nodes in the grid each time.

Comment: You could get better performance out of something like the `foreach` package, if that lets you vectorize or parallelize the nested loop.